Akregator weird bug (I dont get the same error log each time) - Kubuntu 22.04
I use Kubuntu 22.04 and I recently started utilizing Akregator to save myself browsing time searching for articles online. I've been having it set as a startup program for about three months now but just recently ran into this issue. When akregator attempts to open on startup, I see this (I've replicated the error trace in terminal):
~$ akregator
"https://abandonedkansai.com/feed/"
"https://www.democracynow.org/democracynow.rss"
"https://www.democracynow.org/podcast-video.xml"
"https://www.commondreams.org/feeds/feed.rss"
"https://progressive.org/magazine/index.rss"
"https://glaad.org/feed/"
"https://dot.kde.org/rss.xml"
"https://planetkde.org/rss20.xml"
"https://store.kde.org/content.rdf"
"https://planetkde.org/pt-br/rss20.xml"
"https://planet.kde-espana.org/atom.xml"
"http://planet.debian.org/rss20.xml"
"http://www.debian.org/News/news"
"http://planet.ubuntu.com/rss20.xml"
"http://feeds.feedburner.com/ubuntu-fridge"
"http://www.kubuntu.org/news/feed"
Trace/breakpoint trap
:~$ akregator
"https://abandonedkansai.com/feed/"
"https://www.democracynow.org/democracynow.rss"
"https://www.democracynow.org/podcast-video.xml"
"https://www.commondreams.org/feeds/feed.rss"
"https://progressive.org/magazine/index.rss"
"https://glaad.org/feed/"
"https://dot.kde.org/rss.xml"
"https://planetkde.org/rss20.xml"
"https://store.kde.org/content.rdf"
"https://planetkde.org/pt-br/rss20.xml"
"https://planet.kde-espana.org/atom.xml"
"http://planet.debian.org/rss20.xml"
"http://www.debian.org/News/news"
"http://planet.ubuntu.com/rss20.xml"
"http://feeds.feedburner.com/ubuntu-fridge"
"http://www.kubuntu.org/news/feed"
malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected
Unable to start Dr. Konqi

if I keep attempting to open it, I also will sometimes see this error (looks similar):
:~$ akregator
"https://abandonedkansai.com/feed/"
"https://www.democracynow.org/democracynow.rss"
"https://www.democracynow.org/podcast-video.xml"
"https://www.commondreams.org/feeds/feed.rss"
"https://progressive.org/magazine/index.rss"
"https://glaad.org/feed/"
"https://dot.kde.org/rss.xml"
"https://planetkde.org/rss20.xml"
"https://store.kde.org/content.rdf"
"https://planetkde.org/pt-br/rss20.xml"
"https://planet.kde-espana.org/atom.xml"
"http://planet.debian.org/rss20.xml"
"http://www.debian.org/News/news"
"http://planet.ubuntu.com/rss20.xml"
"http://feeds.feedburner.com/ubuntu-fridge"
"http://www.kubuntu.org/news/feed"
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = akregator path = /usr/bin pid = 9596
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/akregator 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi

[2]+  Stopped                 akregator

Why would this happen? I tried reinstalling akregator and I also tried to reinstall what seems to be the offending program dr. konqi but that didn't do me any good because apparently I'd have to reinstall the entire kubuntu-desktop package if I did that. Now, nothing I do can get the akregator program to start up.
